# How to execute simultaneously an $http in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, wordpress

I have a module(app) which contains inside a service(globalService) with `$http`. This module now is included inside another module (invoicesApp) which has a service(invoicesService) too. Using the service of the second module I'm loading the service of the first service and returning back some information. The problem which I'm having is that the parameters of the first service are overridden from the second service and for that reason both `$http` are executing the same request. Here is my code

This is my first Service:

```
(function(angular){
  var app = angular.module('app',[])
    .config(function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
    })
    .service('globalService', function($http, $location,$q){
        console.log("globalService");

        this.getPaging = function()
            {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var paging_parameters = $location.search();
                paging_parameters.action = "client_pagination";
                var req = {
                    url: ajaxpagingscript.ajaxurl,
                    method: "GET",
                    params: paging_parameters
                }
                $http(req).success(function(paging_data) {
                    console.log("globalService " + JSON.stringify(paging_data));
                    deferred.resolve(paging_data.paging);
                }).error(function(data, status, headers)
                {
                    $scope.error = "";
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        });
 })(window.angular);
```

Second Service:

```
(function(angular){

    var invoicesApp = angular.module('invoicesApp',['ngRoute','app'])
         .config(function($locationProvider,$routeProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
            });
         })
        .controller('InvoicesController', ['$scope','transactionService',
        function($scope,invoicesService) {
            $scope.invoices = [];
            console.log("testing");

            var paging = invoicesService.getPaging();
            var promise = invoicesService.getInvoicess();
            promise.then(function(data)
            {
                console.log("invoices " +JSON.stringify(data));
                angular.forEach(data.new_data, function(JSON_ARRAY) {
                    $scope.invoicearray.push(JSON_ARRAY);
                });
            });
        }])
        .service('invoicesService', function(globalService, $http,$location,$q){

            this.getPaging = function() { return globalService.getPaging(); };
            this.getInvoicess = function() {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var invoices_parameters = $location.search();
                    invoices_parameters.action = "collect_invoice_data";

                    var req = {
                        url: ajaxpagingscript.ajaxurl,
                        method: "GET",
                        params: invoices_parameters
                    };
                    $http(req).success(function(data) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers)
                    {
                        $scope.error = "";
                    });

                    return deferred.promise;
            };

        });
})(window.angular);
```

The console.log for both services, returning back the same data. The page that loads this app, loads `invoicesApp` so the globalService is executed fine but the parameters that pass to  `$http` are wrong. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is ajaxpagingscript?  Some global variable?  It looks like both services are requesting the same url.

Comment: ajaxpagingscript is the url that I'm using in the wordpress to call an ajax request and based on the action is choosing the appropriate function.  more info here https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: It looks like you have a promise callback attached to the promise returned by `invoicesService.getInvoicess()`, but not to the promise returned by `invoicesService.getPaging() `

Comment: On the globalService the getPaging function has promise callback

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the function, you need to pass the reference of the function if that is what you are trying to do in invoicesService.

```
this.getPaging = function() { return globalService.getPaging(); };
```

should be

```
this.getPaging = globalService.getPaging;
```

Comment: I changed it to globalService.getPaging the $http is called but the parameters that it sends and the data that it gets are the same getInvoicess, but as you can see from the code that i posted the parameters of the getPaging are different

Comment: I think you need to double check your parameters. You should be able to see that the **action** parameter you are setting is getting sent. Maybe try console.log before sending out the request and make sure that you are able to properly set the action?